# How does a list slice itself?

Tags: python, list

**I am new to python.** The code below returns 8. Why?

```
numbers = [2,3,5,8]
print(numbers[numbers[1]])
```

When working with slicers, I would expect to see:

```
print(numbers[:]) = [2,3,5,8]
or 
print(numbers[:-1]) = [2,3,5]
```

I have never seen something like this:

```
  print(numbers[numbers[1]])
```

Is the list *numbers* slicing itself? And if yes, how is it doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand, break the single line to its components.

```
numbers = [2,3,5,8]

# now instead of `numbers[numbers[1]]` take the innermost portion and give a variable name

inner = numbers[1]
print(inner) #output : 3

#Starting from o, the value of index 1 is 3, So the output will be 3. Now check the outer component

outer = numbers[inner]
print(outer) #Output : 8

'''From the previous step we got the value of inner is 3. 
Now again 3 is considered as index. 
so numbers[3], will return 8 as value of the element with index 3 is 8.
'''
```

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is just nested indexing.
It's not what you think is happening, instead it's actually very trivial.

```
numbers[1] = 3 (for the numbers = [2,3,5,8] )
```

is acting as an index to the outer one

```
number[number[1]] = number[3] = 8
```